# How can I use fold expressions to implement a "domino" or "cascading" update function?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I'm writing a variadic templated function that should implement a "domino" update. That is to say: given a predicate `p`, it should iterate over multiple `lval`s (passed by reference) and assign `val` to them, until `p(val, lval)` returns `false` at which point the process stops.

This is my current implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class Val, class P>
void domino_update(P, Val&) {}

template<class Val, class Lval, class... More, class P>
void domino_update(P p, Val&& val, Lval& lval, More&... more)
{
    if (p(val, lval)) {
        lval = val; // No need to forward since it'd potentially chain more copies anyway
        domino_update(p, val, more...);
    }
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    int i = 8, j = 9, k = 1;
    domino_update(std::less{}, 2, i, j, k);
    std::cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << k << '\n'; // Prints 2 2 1
    return 0;
}
```

However, I don't like the fact that it's recursive.

Can I use a *fold expression* to avoid using recursion (and avoid the need to implement a base case for the template), while maintaining the short-circuiting logic (i.e., `p` should not be called again once it has returned `false`)? How?

Comment: Finally got around to the edit I was talking about. Your own edits helped a lot, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```cpp
template <class P, class Val, class... Lvals>
void domino_update(P p, Val&& val, Lvals&&... lval) {
    ((/*if*/        p(val, lval)
      /*then*/      && (lval = val, true))
      /*and next*/  && ...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qW7PdnW9E)

Answer (score 1):

Challenge accepted.

```
template<typename P, typename Val, typename... Lval>
void domino_update(P p, Val&& val, Lval&... lval)
{
    bool go = true;
    ( (go && (go = p(val, lval)) ? (void(lval = val), 0) : 0), ...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bbEqEzMd1)